# Sending conditional messages in a uml communication diagram

Tags: uml, collaboration-diagram, communication-diagram

I want to represent the following pseudo-code in a communication diagram:

```
A::someoperation(collection)
Begin
  Foreach elem in collection:
    if condition_1 then: 
        create B;
    else if condition_2 then:
        create C;
    else if condition_3 then:
        create D;
  End Foreach;
End someoperation
```

Is there a standard way to do this? I don't think what I did in the following image is correct:

[image: communication diagram]

Comment: LMGTFY example here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=360441&seqNum=6

Comment: Should I answer Superstructures ptc-13-09-05?